# Express session don't persist

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session

I was making a **React project**, and I was using **Express** for backend. I set `http://mini-api.moonlab.ga` as a virtual host for Express server.

I sent a HTTP Request to express server with **`Fetch`**:

```
fetch("http://mini-api.moonlab.ga/login/", {
    credentials: "include"
})
```

and as I expected there was a CORS error. So I installed `cors` package, and I set code like this in Node.js:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credential: true
}));
```

And I respond to client from server like this:

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    const session = req.session;
    if (session.miniAccount == undefined) {
        session.miniAccount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true});
    res.write(String(session.miniAccount));
    res.end();
})
```

After I did like this, there wasn't any CORS error, but the session don't persist. When I send a request again, the session data keeps changes.

Well how to make session persist?

Server's session code:

```
app.use(express_session({
    secret: secret.app_key,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: What are you using for session storage?

Comment: I'm using `express-session`.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question as there are dozens of storage providers for express-session.  Please show your express-session code sp we can see both the storage provider you're using and your session initialization code and session middleware.

Comment: app.use(express_session({
    secret: secret.app_key,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: I added it to question.

Comment: It isn't obvious from the code why that is happening.  You need to debug it from the Chrome debugger, network tab.  There you can see each of your `fetch()` calls and see if the cookie you got back from the first fetch call is being sent with the second fetch call.  If so, then the problem is probably in your server code as it isn't recognizing the returning session cookie.  If not, then the problem is probably in your client code/configuration somehow and the cookie isn't being preserved.  Only you can do this debugging on your actual installation.

Comment: Whoa, I discovered Network tab's "set-cookie" is different for each time. Many blog said putting `credentials: "include"` will preserve information. I'm wondering why it isn't preserved even I put `credentials: "include". Thank you.

Comment: That is indeed the problem.  Because you are making requests to a cross origin, the cookie will be a third party cookie.  There are all sorts of extra controls related to third party cookies and perhaps your cookie is being blocked from storage by the browser because of those settings.  You can start by reading [here](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/third-party-cookie) about third party cookies.  Note, there are browser settings that can limit third party cookies and there are server settings in the cookie itself that can limit third party cookies.

Comment: Yes, I finally solved the problem! I set `"proxy": "http://mini-api.moonlab.ga"` in `package.json`, and edited fetch as `fetch("/login")`, and it worked!! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by editing `package.json`.

I added `"proxy": "mini-api.moonlab.ga"` in `package.json`.

Than I edited `fetch()`.

- previous

```
fetch("http://mini-api.moonlab.ga/login")
```

- new

```
fetch("/login")
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting a maxAge value inside cookie

```
...
const session = require("express-session");
...

app.use(
    session({        
        secret:  secret.app_key,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
        cookie: {          
            maxAge: 3600000 //session expires in 1 hr
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work for me. Anyway thank you for answering.